# How do I get rid of all of the space between the margins and a tabularx environment?

Tags: spacing

## Attempt

I have tried using `\noindent` to remove the space before the `tabularx` environment. However, there is still a small amount of horizontal space before the table. Using the `showframe` package and a vertical lines on the sides of the table I was able to visualize how much space is appearing before the table. The space before the table appears to be just 2 or 3 pixels. By adding `\hspace{-3px}` I was able to get the expected result but I an unsure why the extra space was there.

## Further Research

I found a list of default lengths in the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) but the only relevant length I could locate was `\parindent` which I removed using `\noindent`. I was unable to find the answer to my question in other questions I looked for.

## Sample Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, enumitem, showframe}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\noindent{}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XYZ|}
\Large HEADER & \Large INFO & \Large HERE
\end{tabularx}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0 pt]
\item[\textbf{Question 1}]\ \\
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Sample Code Output

[image: Output]

## Expected Code Output

[image: Expected Output]

## Post Note

As this is my first post, I welcome feedback on how to improve my question for current and future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that by putting the `{}` after `\noindent` you've also inserted a space afterwards. The `{}` is not necessary and can be removed to get the desired output.

You've asked your question well.

Comment: I have removed the tabularx and overleaf tags because the extra space was not related to either. Are there any other tags I should include?